# Acess getWindow method in simple java class

Tags: android, android-view

I am using method `Window wingdow = getWindow()` in my `Activity` class. Now i want to use this method in simple java class but it get errors `not resolve method`. I also use `contex`t but it also get erros. How can we access it in simple java class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create instance passing `Activity` as parameter of constructor

```
MyClass myClass= new MyClass(this);
```

And use `getWindow()` method like here

```
public Class MyClass
 {
    public Activity activity;
    public MyClass(Activity act)
    {
         this.activity = act;

    }
   public void otherMethod(){
      Window window = act.getWindow()
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks its working, but i can't vote u because my reputation point is low

Comment: @shaileshojha, It's my pleasure to hear such, No problem bro. Happy coding.